# Android open a client socket but not continue

Tags: android, sockets

I have a question about Android client Socket

my target server won't send message every second,but when somethings happened

the server will push some string to my Android phone

The server works correctly ,cause my iOS app works fine

But in android , i just get the message - 200 OK

but the following message won't come in

even though the server had push some string already

this is my code to open socket

```
public void _openSocket() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String Stream = "GET /audio.event HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    String Stream2 = "Host: 192.168.30.1\r\n";
    String Stream3 = "\r\n";
    sb.append(Stream);
    sb.append(Stream2);
    sb.append(Stream3);

    Log.i("ray", "Connecting Socket...");
    Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.30.1",80);
    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            inputStream));
    DataOutputStream os = null;
    os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    os.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
    String data = is.readLine();
    Log.i("data", data);
}
```

could anyone tell me what did i missing?

thanks for your great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the second line:

```
os.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
os.flush();
```

This will cause the packet to be sent. Otherwise, the server will wait for the packet to be big enough to be "worth' sending